# How to prove $n^5-5n^3+4n = 5!{n+2\choose 5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I understand the answer, but I am stuck on blue underline part. Please someone describe the blue underline section and how it's come from. Thank you.

**Source**

*Number theory: Structure , Examples and Problems* by Titu Andreescu .

Comment: $$n(n^4\!-\!5n^2\!+\!4) = \color{#c00}n(\color{#0a0}{n^2\!-\!1})(n^2\!-\!4) = (n\!+\!2)(\color{#0a0}{n\!+\!1})\color{#c00}n(\color{#0a0}{n\!-\!1})(n\!-\!2) = \dfrac{(n\!+\!2)!}{(n\!-\!3)!}  = 5!{n\!+\!2\choose 5}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$5!\binom{n+2}{5} = 5!\frac{(n+2)!}{5!(n-3)!} = \frac{(n+2)!}{(n-3)!} $$$$= (n+2)(n+1)(n)(n-1)(n-2)=n^5-5n^3+4n.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $$
\left( \begin{array}{l}
 n + 2 \\ 
 \,\,\,\,5 \\ 
 \end{array} \right) = \frac{{\left( {n + 2} \right)!}}{{\left( {n + 2 - 5} \right)!\,5!}}
$$
it is
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 5!\left( \begin{array}{l}
 n + 2 \\ 
 \,\,\,\,5 \\ 
 \end{array} \right) = \frac{{\left( {n + 2} \right)!}}{{\left( {n - 3} \right)!\,}} = \frac{{\left( {n + 2} \right)(n + 1)n(n - 1)(n - 2)(n - 3)!}}{{(n - 3)!}} =  \\ 
  \\ 
  = \left( {n + 2} \right)(n + 1)n(n - 1)(n - 2) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
that is what you need.